# Node.JS local hosting server manager

Tags: node.js

I'm searching for a **local** hosting server manager for my Node.JS applications that lives on different ports.

All I can find is cloud-based hosting such as: nodejitsu, nodecloud, nodester, heroku and so on.

Is there any hosting environment that can run locally on my personal computer ?

**EDITED:**

I'm looking for something like Microsoft IIS Server Manager.

That way I can manage my different server apps on different ports/configurations.

Comment: I don't think such thing exists,  node.js is still young and it doesn't have billion dollar budgets backing its development. Try https://npmjs.org/package/forever or search a npmjs.org for sysadmin packages that might suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

What prevents you from downloading node.js from http://nodejs.org/ and installing it on machine of your choice? That's all you need for running node only applications.

Answer (score 0):

Node.js based websites write server software in JavaScript and run it with Node. It isn't used in conjunction with a regular webserver (except when that server operates as a proxy).

If you take a look at, to pick one based on it being at the front of your list, the [getting started guide for nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/getting-started/) you will see the code to run an HTTP server in the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have a public IP & domain-name set up (or use something like [localtunnel](http://shtylman.com/localtunnel/)), it is just a question about starting a Node.js webserver:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:80/');
```

(Taken from [Nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org/).)